# How to save speicific data of a contact in .vcf file

Tags: android, backup, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I am working in a project that will backup all contacts as a .vcf file in sdcard. At this time, I am able to get all information of a contact ( including number, emails, birthday etc.... ).

But I want to get specific information from contacts. (ex: just number).

How can I do it?

I am trying to modify [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046936/android-how-to-save-contacts-to-sdcard-as-vcard-without-duplicates) codes... but cannot solve my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard) can parse vCard files (disclaimer: I am the author xD )

```
Reader reader = ...
List<VCard> vcards = Ezvcard.parse(reader).all();
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it free to use in any application?

Comment: It can be freely used in any commercial or non-commercial application.

Answer (score 0):

To get contacts information, see this solution: [How to get contact number from contactlist in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044399/how-to-get-contact-number-from-contactlist-in-android)

As to saving in .vcf file please provide some code.